# Get length of delimited string in java?

Tags: java, string, delimiter

Can anyone tell me what function I could use to get the number of delimited strings within a delimited string? For example, if I had

```
String time = "hh:mm:ss";
```

the function would return `3` because there are three separated strings: `hh`,`mm`,`ss`
Thanks!

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
"hh:mm:ss".split(":").length
```

You can read more about the `split` method [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).